# Regarding Admob in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, ads

I have implement admob in my application and ads sowing properly. Also a/c is created on Admob for getting admob unit id.
All working fine but no impression count and clicks count increased past 2 weeks. Even I clarify admob unit id, its correct. Any reason behind it, your help will be appreciate.

Also another thing is, my logcat showing me:

03-03 12:29:32.982  28406-28406/com.sudosaints.admobdemo I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.

03-03 12:29:32.983  28406-28406/com.sudosaints.admobdemo I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("6B039BBD4D66338A349104EF25FC47D6") to get test ads on this device.

03-03 12:29:34.123  28406-28406/com.sudosaints.admobdemo I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.

Why my logcat showing me like this above?
In my whole project there is no any connection with "addTestDevice("6B039BBD4D66338A349104EF25FC47D6")" this id.

Any reason behind such type of log. or It is default?

Below is my code.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_unit_id));

        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        /*AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("sdfsdf").build();*/

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.xyz.xyz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you trying with the debug or with release app build? If it's a debug build, you will not get any impressions on the Admob. Also wait till 24 hrs after hits with released app.

Comment: Currently it is in debug build

Comment: It will work only on release app build?

Comment: Yes, please try with the release build.

Comment: and 1 more thing, why my logcat showing me same log in every project like:
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("6B039BBD4D66338A349104EF25FC47D6")

what is relation with this id: 6B039BBD4D66338A349104EF25FC47D6

Comment: While your testing with the debug app, it suggest to add the test device to the Admob to receive test ads. Why so, because the test ads and the actual ads impressions may get combined and the final report is not accurate and has the test results.

Comment: Don't call `displayInterstitial()` form `onAdLoaded()`. It provides a poor user experience and will get your account banned.